How can I estimate this summation?
\begin{align}\sum_{n=114}^\infty\frac{n\sum_{k=0}^{112}(-1)^k {113 \choose k+1} ({k+1})^{n-1} }{114^{n-1}}=\,?\end{align}
I want to calculate the expected value of the number of implementations to collect all 114 types when the probability of each of the 114 types of products is the same.AND You can only get one product at a time.
Since E(X)=\begin{align}\sum_{n=114}^\infty n p_n\end{align}, I asked chatgpt and https://www.wolframalpha.com/ but they can't calculate. So I want to estimate it in the power form of 10.
I tried to n=114 to 2000 in excel. Afrer then I want claim that n>=2001 then the summation will less than 1 but it failed. Can you estimate this value?

This just sounds like a variant of coupon collector, no?

maybe Yes. I can calculate when the type of collection is low number. But this answer is too big that occur overflow_error. It may numerical analysis problem.
